# Intrustion Detection System on the AWS platform

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, intrusion-detection

Is there a solution for an intrustion detection system on the AWS platform? Would you have to go 3rd party or do they have their own offering?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very general. IDS systems look a bit different in the cloud compared to on-premise "traditional" setups and AWS provides a wide array of options in the security area for example: IAM, CloudTrail & VPC Flow Logs. They can serve as building blocks for IDS depending on what you want to achieve.

If you are asking about more "traditional" IDS systems (network-sniffing boxes), there are lots of solutions available on AWS Marketplace via partners, for example: Sophos, AlertLogic, TrendMicro, CloudPassage.

The best recommendation I could give you is watching below videos to get a better overview what are your options:

[AWS re:Invent 2015 | (SEC205) Learn How to Hackproof Your Cloud Using Native AWS Tools](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ERy_YomoYk)

[AWS re:Invent 2014 | (SEC402) Intrusion Detection in the Cloud](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WUQNeMhkaco)

[Intrusion Detection in the Cloud (SEC402) | AWS re:Invent 2013](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aGfKCmnmh5g)

Comment: Sorry about the generality. I guess I just wanted to know the various options. These are great resources, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Snort](https://www.snort.org/) is a well known Intrusion Detection System. [Bro](https://www.bro.org/) is another well known IDS